# Is there any way in Ubuntu 17.10 to disable touchpad gestures with Xorg?

Tags: xorg, touchpad, 17.10, logitech

I have Logitech 400K+ keyboard with integrated touchpad. It works ok but I would like to disable gestures like pinch etc. and keeping only the two finger scroll and pointer movement.

However from the settings or using gnome-tweaks I cannot find any configuration option for the touchpad.

Also I tried to modify the file /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf

in this way:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
        MatchIsTouchpad "on"
        MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
        Driver "libinput"
    Option "Tapping" "false"
    Option "TappingDrag" "false"
    Option "TappingDragLock" "false"
EndSection
```

but the tapping is still there.

Any idea?

UPDATE

As suggested by Charles Green I have run:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech K400 Plus                        id=8    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Eee PC WMI hotkeys                        id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Logitech K400 Plus                        id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
and

$ xinput list-props 8
Device 'Logitech K400 Plus':
    Device Enabled (153):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (155): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    libinput Accel Speed (287): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Speed Default (288): 0.000000
    libinput Accel Profiles Available (289):    1, 1
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled (290):   1, 0
    libinput Accel Profile Enabled Default (291):   1, 0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled (292):   0
    libinput Natural Scrolling Enabled Default (293):   0
    libinput Send Events Modes Available (272): 1, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (273):    0, 0
    libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (274):    0, 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled (294): 0
    libinput Left Handed Enabled Default (295): 0
    libinput Scroll Methods Available (296):    0, 0, 1
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled (297):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Scroll Method Enabled Default (298):   0, 0, 0
    libinput Button Scrolling Button (299): 2
    libinput Button Scrolling Button Default (300): 2
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled (301):    0
    libinput Middle Emulation Enabled Default (302):    0
    Device Node (275):  "/dev/input/event8"
    Device Product ID (276):    1133, 16461
    libinput Drag Lock Buttons (303):   <no items>
    libinput Horizontal Scroll Enabled (304):   1
```

and switched some props, but nothing changes.

Comment: There is not that option showing

Comment: I realised that, tested on wrong VM.. sorry

Comment: Try this: synclient ClickFinger3=2
synclient TapButton3=2

Comment: Just to be clear, under 17.10, you're explicitly running an Xorg session, correct (Wayland is now the default)?

Comment: @richbl yes I disabled wayland due to conflicts with nvidia driver

Comment: Please dont vandalise your post.

Comment: Sure you are looking at the properties of your touchpad? Try also listing and changing props of device 4.

Answer (score 0):

## Ubuntu 17.10 uses Wayland

From the [libinput](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/libinput/) wiki page:

> libinput is a library to handle input devices in Wayland compositors and to provide a generic X.Org input driver. It provides
> device detection, device handling, input device event processing and
> abstraction so minimize the amount of custom input code compositors
> need to provide the common set of functionality that users expect.

## `libinput` and `synaptics` can be both be installed

If you have libinput and synaptics installed in parallel with default configuration (i.e. no files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` for either), synaptics will take precedence due to its higher numeric order `70-` in the default installation directory. To avoid this, you can symlink the default libinput configuration (`40-libinput.conf`) to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` where directory search order precedence over `70-synaptics.conf` will take place instead:

```
$ sudo ln -s /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/40-libinput.conf
```

If you do have `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/` configuration files for both, the libinput file must be ordered second. If you want to disable libinput (and fallback to older drivers) - just remove the previously created symbolic link from `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

## Check what `libinput` is managing

One way to check which devices are managed by libinput is the xorg logfile. For example, the following:

```
$ grep -e "Using input driver 'libinput'" /path/to/Xorg.0.log

[    28.799] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    28.847] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Video Bus'
[    28.853] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Power Button'
[    28.860] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'Sleep Button'
[    28.872] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard'
[    28.878] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad'
[    28.886] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'TPPS/2 IBM TrackPoint'
[    28.895] (II) Using input driver 'libinput' for 'ThinkPad Extra Buttons'
```

is a notebook without any configuration files in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`, i.e. devices are autodetected.

## Choose `synaptics` driver over `lipinput` for one device

Of course you can elect to use an alternative driver for one device and libinput for others. A number of factors may influence which driver to use. For example, in comparison to Touchpad Synaptics the libinput driver has fewer options to customize touchpad behaviour to one's own taste, but far more programmatic logic to process multitouch events (e.g. palm detection as well). Hence, it makes sense to try the alternative, if you are experiencing problems on your hardware with one driver or the other.

#### Reference

Answer from [ArchLinux Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Libinput) which has many more details.

Comment: tried but it doesn't work. Touchpad is still full on.

Comment: @Randomize I changed the answer to possible snaptics vs libinput conflict.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands for disabling multifinger gestures:

```
synclient ClickFinger3=2
synclient TapButton3=2
```

Comment: I have installed and uninstalled the synaptic package to run you suggested commands (along with libinput and geis-tools) but nothing changes unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities - the first is to disable touching:

For my device, I can list the available properties with

```
xinput list-prop 12
```

Where '12' is the device ID provided by `xinput`

My devices properties list has only a few 'tapping' options, the one I am interested in is "libinput tapping enabled"

```
xinput set-prop 12 276 0
```

then sets all tapping functions of my touchpad off.

Your touchpad of course, may have a different id number and property number - you can find the device number with `xinput` and the property number with `xinput list-props <device-number>`

I could also have specified

```
xinput set-prop 'SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad' 'libinput Tapping Enabled' 0
```

and then I would not have needed the device or property number.

---

The second possibility is that the packages 'touchegg' and/or 'geis-tools' are installed on your system.  You can start the program `touchegg` to control it's parameters, or uninstall these packages.

Comment: I have not `tapping Enabled` like yours. I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

I've added this as a separate answer, well, because.

Apparently you can change your keyboard tap-to-click *at the keyboard*, by presseing the blue Fn key, and then clicking the left mouse button.  Please see https://www.logitech.com/en-us/manuals/11916, in the section "K400 Plus Extras"

as for multi-touch gestures:  Please execute

```
lsmod | grep 'evdev\|mtdev'
```

If either the 'evdev' or 'mtdev' modules are present, please attempt to remove them:

```
sudo modprobe -r mtdev
```

or

```
sudo modprobe -r evdev
```

These are the kernel modules that are used in interpreting multitouch gestures (https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch) If removal of the modules creates the effect that you are looking for, you could add them to '/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf'

Comment: In part the manual:) solved the situation. I am able to disable the tap-button. The pinch unfortunately is still there, and from the manual looks like it depends on the OS. The `lsmod` didn't return anything so no module installed.

Comment: @Randomize - I think I've reached the limit of what I can find through modest searching:  There is a series of libraries and applications referred to as "grail", which are apparently used to handle multi-touch devices - this may help in your application (I don't have a multi-touch device) - more information is at [https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/+source/grail](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/artful/+source/grail)

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to linux, and regarding all the "solutions" i found on the internet about disabling those gestures, none of them worked for me, having a 2 in 1 tablet with a trackpad. 
I found a solution by myself. Go to Settings > Keyboard > Shorcuts, and disable all the shortcuts related to your trackpad. (swiping left opens apps etc.). This would work 100%.
Reminder: it wont't disable the two-finger scrolling, and the zoom.